# Why "WHERE" exists in SQL? Because "HAVING" can do its tasks plus more than that

Tags: sql, having

Why "WHERE" exists in SQL? Because "HAVING" can do its tasks plus more than that

Comment: Huh?  This is not true at all.  `HAVING` can only be used after `GROUP BY`.  Your question makes no sense.

Comment: Having is executed after query has been executed while where filters the records before.  Normally performance benefit using where clause

Answer (score 4):

Try using HAVING to do this query:

> Sum the total sales per country for product 'XYZ'

```
SELECT country, SUM(amount)
FROM sales
GROUP BY country
HAVING product = 'XYZ'
```

No, that won't do it, because the groups will include sales for all products. And the HAVING condition is invalid because there are multiple products in each grouping.

The purpose of HAVING is to filter groups, *after* an aggregation is applied.

The purpose of WHERE is to filter rows, *before* an aggregation is applied.

```
SELECT country, SUM(amount)
FROM sales
WHERE product = 'XYZ'
GROUP BY country
```

Comment: `SELECT country, sum(sales) FROM (SELECT product, country, sum(sales) AS sales FROM t GROUP BY product, country HAVING product = 'XYZ') t GROUP BY country` ;-)

Comment: @LukasEder, That yields the correct results, but is needlessly verbose and difficult to understand.

Comment: You said *"Try using HAVING to do this query:"*, I delivered... ;-)

Comment: Bless your heart! :-)